# Borders dont appear to NatTable Cells in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

I have tried that with both : Setting a theme configuration and Registering a style with border style in Config Registry. But I am not seeing the borders. Is there anything else I am missing?

In my postConstruct method I am initialising NatTable as follows :

```
    final ThemeConfiguration modernTheme = new ModernNatTableThemeConfiguration(imageRightUp, imageTreeRightDown);

    TextPainter textPainter = new TextPainter(true, false);
    ImagePainter imagePainter = new ImagePainter(threeDots);
    CellPainterDecorator cellPainterDecorator = new CellPainterDecorator(textPainter, CellEdgeEnum.RIGHT, imagePainter);

    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
            CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
            cellPainterDecorator,
            DisplayMode.NORMAL,
            LABEL_1);

    Style style = new Style();

    style.setAttributeValue(
            CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR,
            GUIHelper.getColor(44, 104, 125));
    style.setAttributeValue(
            CellStyleAttributes.FOREGROUND_COLOR,
            GUIHelper.COLOR_WHITE);
    style.setAttributeValue(
            CellStyleAttributes.BORDER_STYLE,
            new BorderStyle(5, GUIHelper.COLOR_BLACK, LineStyleEnum.SOLID));

    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
            // attribute to apply
            CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE,
            // value of the attribute
            style,
            // apply during normal rendering i.e not
            // during selection or edit
            DisplayMode.NORMAL,
            // apply the above for all cells with this label
           LABEL_1);

    configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
            // attribute to apply
            CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE,
            // value of the attribute
            style,
            // apply during normal rendering i.e not
            // during selection or edit
            DisplayMode.NORMAL,
            // apply the above for all cells with this label
            LABEL_2);

    NatTable natTable = new NatTable(parent, viewportLayer, false);
    GridData d = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1,1);
    natTable.setLayoutData(d);
    natTable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
    natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultTreeLayerConfiguration(treeLayer));
    natTable.setTheme(modernTheme);
    natTable.configure();
```

Also this is Theme Configuration :

```
public class ModernNatTableThemeConfiguration extends DefaultNatTableThemeConfiguration {


    public ModernNatTableThemeConfiguration( Image imageRightUp, Image imageTreeRightDown ){

        TreeImagePainter treeImagePainter = new TreeImagePainter(
                false,
                imageRightUp, imageTreeRightDown, null); //$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$
        this.treeStructurePainter = new BackgroundPainter(new PaddingDecorator(
                new IndentedTreeImagePainter(10, null, CellEdgeEnum.LEFT,
                        treeImagePainter, false, 2, true), 0, 5, 0, 5, false));

       TreeImagePainter treeSelectionImagePainter = new TreeImagePainter(
                false,
                imageRightUp, imageTreeRightDown, null); //$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$
        this.treeStructureSelectionPainter = new BackgroundPainter(
                new PaddingDecorator(new IndentedTreeImagePainter(10, null,
                        CellEdgeEnum.LEFT, treeSelectionImagePainter, false, 2,
                        true), 0, 5, 0, 5, false));

        this.treeBgColor = GUIHelper.getColor(44, 104, 125);
        this.treeFgColor = GUIHelper.getColor(44, 104, 125);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need to clear about the terms. Do you want to remove the borders or the grid lines? Because you specify a border in your style configuration, so the border should be there.

If you want to get rid of the grid lines, you need to configure the `CellLayerPainter`.

This can be done like this for example:

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
            CellConfigAttributes.RENDER_GRID_LINES, 
            Boolean.FALSE);
```

BTW, it is not a good practice to directly modify the `ConfigRegistry` like you are doing in your code. You should create an `IConfiguration` (e.g. `AbstractRegistryConfiguration`) and register the `IConfiguration` to your NatTable instance instead. Otherwise `NatTable#configure()` might override your changes at configuration time.

This is explained here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_configuration

Comment: Thanks Dirk, I should modify the question. I wanted to remove grid lines. yes. I just checked couple of Border Styles if there is some effect. Those are in the source. As you said I was just about to create IConfiguaration. Thanks.

Comment: Currently it is only possible to enable/disable the grid line rendering or specify the grid line color via configuration. To support a different line style you need to implement a custom GridLineCellLayerPainter and set it to the NatTable or an underlying layer.

Feel free to file an enhancement ticket to add support for grid line styling via configuration.

Comment: I just saw that now the title is about not rendered borders. This is because there is no `LineBorderDecorator` configured for the treePainter. To support that you need to wrap your `CellPainterDecorator` in a `LineBorderDecorator`

Comment: Dirk, As you said I created the `IConfiguaration` instance in which I am making gridlines disappear. With this, I am also setting a theme which has different tree up and down images. If theme is set to NatTable, it overrides the `IConfiguaration`  and still grid line appear. Is there any way to avoid this because I want custom tree-up and down images as well as no grid lines

Comment: Themes are special compared to default `IConfiguration` as they need to be set AFTER `NatTable#configure()`. This is to avoid the overriding in the configuration initialization and to support theme switching at runtime.

https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_110.php

Seems I need to finish the styling chapter soon.

For further question please use our forum: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=240

Comment: With respect to my above comment, I solved those grid line problem by setting its changing its colour to same as background of tree. :/ I will do as you said. Thanks a ton!

Comment: If my answer was the correct one and helped you in solving your issue, please accept it as the correct answer to help others that have a similar issue.